# Adding a date to a formula in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

`=$M2="COMPLETED"`

I am using this formula to shade a row when COMPLETED is written in column M, but I would prefer the 'date' or 'COMPLETED and the date' but can't seem to work out how to do this.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: LibreOffice Calc has a `LEFT()` function that returns the *n* first characters of a string. Might that be what you need? (If Excel also has it, that would be something like `=LEFT($M2;9)="COMPLETED"`.)

Comment: It isn't clear whether you're referring to what you want displayed in the cell or what you want to test.  Is the problem how to display the date as part of the cell text, or how to test the cell when it contains a date (and is the specific date irrelevant to the test)?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I do want the date to display, hope that helps

Comment: So you want M2 to contain something like "06/19/2015" or "Completed 06/19/2015", and then you want to test for whether M2 contains any date (1st case), or "Completed" (2nd case)?  Or are you looking for the date in a different (result) cell?  Can you expand your question with an example that shows all of the relevant cells, conditions, and results?

Comment: Yes I want M2 to contain something like "06/19/2015" or "Completed 06/19/2015" and this content will trigger the whole row to change colour

Comment: Do you need to test the date against a criteria, such as is the date today or earlier?

Comment: Without an example, your question is too ambiguous.  You have three answers so far, each interpretting your question differently.  For example, is M2 just a completion indicator that will contain a relevant date, and you want to simply test for any entry, or are you testing for a specific date or date range?  Please add an example that shows the relevant cells, what you want them to contain, how the content will get there, exactly what condition you want to test for, the logic, the desired result, and how you determine the result.

Comment: @Julie Please post a screen shot of *what your spreadsheet would look like* when you want your entire row to change color.  Providing a picture will go a long way to clear up the difficulty you're having describing with words what data your conditional format is working with.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your situation, there are three relevant columns:

- a column with a completion date (let's say it's in column `L`)
- column `M`, which may contain the string `COMPLETED`
- a column where you want your output (let's say it's column `N`)

You use the formula `=$M2="COMPLETED"`, which results in `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If I understand correctly, instead of true/false, you want the completion date (from column L).

If that's, the case, [use the `IF` function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), which has the following format:  `IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )`. In your case, this will be: `=IF($M2="COMPLETED";$L2;"")` (the last double quote leaves an empty string if it's not completed.) A more verbose options, using string concatenation is this: `=IF($M2="COMPLETED";"Completed at: " & $L2;"Not completed yet")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with the most complicated situation.

Column M contains a date. If the date in column is today or earlier, you want to add a fill color to the row that cell is in.

You clearly know how to change the color of the row, but you are looking for a formula to determine when to change the color.

You are going to test to see if the date in the cell is less than or equal to today's date. The formula you can enter is `=$M2<=(TODAY())`

This formula will continually update, provided you have automatic recalculation turned on. IF you need to test against a specific date, it is easiest to have that date in a specific cell and use the cell reference. For example: `=$M2<=$Q$2`

Answer (score 0):

For the date, just use

```
=$M2<=TODAY()
```

For 'COMPLETED' and the date use

```
=AND(LEFT($M2,9)="COMPLETED",DATEVALUE(RIGHT($M2,10))<=TODAY())
```

This works for the format you specified in your comment, "06/19/2015". It will be much more robust if you just use a date and check against that, since Excel will then treat the cell as a date as opposed to a string.

Comment: That tests for a specific date.  If I understand the question, the cell (or column?) is a completion indicator that would contain the relevant date.  So the test is really for an indicator of completion.  If that's the case, it would need to be for the presence of any date or the string "Completion" (which would probably be easier).

Comment: @fixer1234, I see what you're saying, I'll put up a third case.

Comment: @fixer1234, nevermind, it actually can get complicated since there is no ISDATE function in Excel, but we just don't have enough specs here to be sure what the OP is asking.